# Fail event returns false value of tab, when Radwindow is used

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, telerik

I have a problem.
onclick second of tab  isn't returning false.

asp.net code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        var searchString = "1";
        radopen("WebForm4.aspx?id=" + searchString, "radwindow");
    }
</script>

<a onclick="change(); return false;" href="thaydoimatkhau.aspx" class="matkhau">change</a>
<telerik:RadWindowManager  VisibleStatusbar="false" Width="650" Height="500" ReloadOnShow="true" EnableShadow="true" ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" ShowContentDuringLoad="false">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="radwindow" runat="server" Width="650"  Height="680" Behaviors="Close" >
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Demo code:
When clicked first, it shows the window form Webform.aspx

But if it's clicked second, it loads the parent page.

I don't want the parent page to load.
It only shows the window form on the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have URL in `href` if you use RadWindow.

It should be like this -

```
<a onclick="change(); return false;" href="#" class="matkhau">change</a>
...
```

Comment: use href="javascript:void(0);" to prevent the anchor's behavior as well. With the sharp sign your page may scroll to the top (which is what such an anchor would usually do).

Comment: @rdmptn Good trick. I like that approach too. Thanks for sharing.